# Embed a Twitter profile, not a timeline

Tags: twitter, wordpress

I have been looking for a solution for embedding Twitter user profiles, but have come up empty so far. What I'm looking for is something similar to how Twitter pops up a nice profile overview when you click a username on twitter.com. I took a screencap of my profile so you can see below what I'm talking about.

[image]

I don't have any need for the user timeline or anything like that, just the user info, the cover photo background would be nice as well as a link to follow the person. I took a look through Twitters embed code builder but there didn't seem to be anything that really fit the bill. I am using Wordpress so a plugin solution could be viable, but if it's just a code embed that is fine as well.

Comment: Is this for a single profile? Everything in the profile is static except Tweets, Following and Followers.

Comment: @topdown yes, this would be for a single user profile. I had been hoping to create multiple embeds of this on a page, that would show different users.

Comment: any news on this? looking for the same thing, hope for an embeddable solution

Comment: @ducu I wasn't able to find anything that worked for this particular issue. I know it's something you could probably build using the API, but that's a little out of my depth.

Comment: hey just found this, worth looking into it
https://dev.twitter.com/web/intents#user-intent

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no embed functionality that I know of for the profile summary, however you can call the api to get profile information from Twitter in two ways:

1. For one use at a time: [/users/show](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show), or
2. For up to 100 users at once: [/users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/lookup)

You can then take the returned json and style it to match the twitter format or any other style you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Not really embed but this could work for you too https://dev.twitter.com/web/intents#user-intent

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation for the button, this require some work to add the profile picture and the background picture

Icon SVG code:

```
  <symbol id="twitter" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M459.37 151.716c.325 4.548.325 9.097.325 13.645 0 138.72-105.583 298.558-298.558 298.558-59.452 0-114.68-17.219-161.137-47.106 8.447.974 16.568 1.299 25.34 1.299 49.055 0 94.213-16.568 130.274-44.832-46.132-.975-84.792-31.188-98.112-72.772 6.498.974 12.995 1.624 19.818 1.624 9.421 0 18.843-1.3 27.614-3.573-48.081-9.747-84.143-51.98-84.143-102.985v-1.299c13.969 7.797 30.214 12.67 47.431 13.319-28.264-18.843-46.781-51.005-46.781-87.391 0-19.492 5.197-37.36 14.294-52.954 51.655 63.675 129.3 105.258 216.365 109.807-1.624-7.797-2.599-15.918-2.599-24.04 0-57.828 46.782-104.934 104.934-104.934 30.213 0 57.502 12.67 76.67 33.137 23.715-4.548 46.456-13.32 66.599-25.34-7.798 24.366-24.366 44.833-46.132 57.827 21.117-2.273 41.584-8.122 60.426-16.243-14.292 20.791-32.161 39.308-52.628 54.253z" /></symbol>
```

SASS/CSS:

```
.twitter a  
  font-family: "Roboto", "Noto Sans", "Open Sans", "sans-serif"
  display: inline-flex
  color: #fff
  border-radius: 5px
  background: #1b95e0
  padding: .4em .8em
  text-decoration: none
  font-weight: bold
  text-align: left
```

HTML:

```
<div class="twitter" style="height: 35px; width: 240px;"><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://twitter.com/LinuxHacksOrg">
<svg height="20px" width="20px" style="margin-right: 5px; fill: #fff;">
<use xlink:href="/assets/imgs/res/icons-full.svg#twitter"></use></svg>
Follow us @LinuxHacksOrg</a></div>
```

```html
<style>
.twitter a {
  font-family: "Roboto", "Noto Sans", "Open Sans", "sans-serif";
  display: inline-flex;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #1b95e0;
  padding: .4em .8em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
}
</style>

<div class="twitter" style="height: 35px; width: 300px;"><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://twitter.com/LinuxHacksOrg">
<svg height="20px" width="20px" style="margin-right: 5px; fill: #fff;" viewBox="0 0 512 512" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path d="M459.37 151.716c.325 4.548.325 9.097.325 13.645 0 138.72-105.583 298.558-298.558 298.558-59.452 0-114.68-17.219-161.137-47.106 8.447.974 16.568 1.299 25.34 1.299 49.055 0 94.213-16.568 130.274-44.832-46.132-.975-84.792-31.188-98.112-72.772 6.498.974 12.995 1.624 19.818 1.624 9.421 0 18.843-1.3 27.614-3.573-48.081-9.747-84.143-51.98-84.143-102.985v-1.299c13.969 7.797 30.214 12.67 47.431 13.319-28.264-18.843-46.781-51.005-46.781-87.391 0-19.492 5.197-37.36 14.294-52.954 51.655 63.675 129.3 105.258 216.365 109.807-1.624-7.797-2.599-15.918-2.599-24.04 0-57.828 46.782-104.934 104.934-104.934 30.213 0 57.502 12.67 76.67 33.137 23.715-4.548 46.456-13.32 66.599-25.34-7.798 24.366-24.366 44.833-46.132 57.827 21.117-2.273 41.584-8.122 60.426-16.243-14.292 20.791-32.161 39.308-52.628 54.253z" />
</svg>
Follow us @LinuxHacksOrg</a></div>
```

Comment: @jbwharris I updated the code with a snippet ;) ... the main advantage here is to avoid loading bloated Twitter's js